# My algorithm is returning unsolved answers. How do I fix this?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to create a Sudoku solver which takes numpy arrays and returns the correct answer. However, at the moment, any numpy array which I try returns an unsolved answer.

I think the problem is with:

```
return
solved = puzzle.copy()
solver(puzzle)
```

However, I can't figure out exactly why. In the code above, I'm trying to store the solution. Though, it's clear I'm not doing this correctly, or I'm attempt to do it in the wrong place.

**What should I be doing instead to properly return the solved puzzle?**

Full code segment below:

```
def solver(puzzle):
    empty_cell = find_empty(puzzle)
    if not empty_cell:
        return True

    else:
        for num in range(1, 10):
            if valid(puzzle, num, empty_cell):
                puzzle[empty_cell[0]][empty_cell[1]] = num 
                if solver(puzzle):
                    return
                    solved = puzzle.copy()
                    solver(puzzle)
                puzzle[empty_cell[0]][empty_cell[1]] = 0
        return False
```

Comment: You have some bad indentation in your code. Can you fix it so it's clear where the indentation is and where it isn't? For example, I bet the line `empty_cell = find_empty(puzzle)` is indented to the right. Indentation in Python is important and can cause errors.

Comment: Can you review your code, so all the spaces / tabs are in the correct place? In the current form the `return` before `solved = puzzle.copy()` is I belive not inside a function and even if it were, everything after the `return` statement would never get called

Comment: Fixed the indentation now. Appears to have been a copy and paste issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by Szala in the comments you have code after a return statement which would never execute. Since you want to return the puzzle properly try this:

```
def solver(puzzle):
    empty_cell = find_empty(puzzle)
    if not empty_cell:
        return puzzle.copy()

    else:
        for num in range(1, 10):
            if valid(puzzle, num, empty_cell):
                puzzle[empty_cell[0]][empty_cell[1]] = num 
                returned_value = solver(puzzle)
                if not returned_value is False:
                    return returned_value
                puzzle[empty_cell[0]][empty_cell[1]] = 0
        return False
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reviewing this. From what I understand adding return puzzle.copy() creates a deep copy of the puzzle. Is this where the "finished" sudoku is returned? 

Adding the returned value makes sense, though, I'm getting two errors now: ValueError: Traceback (most recent call last) and ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

Comment: @SoyLatte I just wrote that because you did, Infact I think just returning the same object would be fine as well as you are already changing it before returning and have not restored it before returning.

Comment: Oh my bad! Numpy arrays don't have a truth value, I'll edit one second.

Comment: Thanks a lot this works now and I'm now more familiar with what that truth value error means. Thank you a lot for your help.